# VBA For loop within IF and For Loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to write a macro to put the name of the steward in a cell if they are assigned to that category. I wrote this code so far but it isn't working. I'm trying to get it so that if a cell of a column in one worksheet matches the cell of another worksheet and if it does, then it will print the name of the steward in a separate cell to identify that that category is owned by that person.

The numbers are in the worksheet Demetri in the range of E27 to E38 and I want to see if the cells in the range BE4 to BE163803 from the worksheet Share_Dump are in the range from the Demetri worksheet.

```
Sub steward_products()
Dim d, s As Worksheet

Set d = Worksheets("Demetri")
Set s = Worksheets("Share_Dump")

For i = 4 To 163803 Step 1
    For j = 27 To 38 Step 1
        If s.Cells(i, 3) = d.Cells(j, 5) Then
            s.Cells(i, 57) = "Demetri"
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: I think you forgot to explain what the problem is.

Comment: btw: `Dim d, s As Worksheet` means `Dim d As Variant, s As Worksheet` - You probably wanted `Dim d As Worksheet, s As Worksheet`

Comment: That's *a lot* of iterations! Reading/writing from/to worksheet cells is probably the single slowest thing you can do in a loop; consider leveraging `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` instead of nesting loops... that said it looks like having `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($C4, 'Demetri'!$E$27:$E$38, 0), ""), "Demetri")` in column 57 / row 4 of the `Share_Dump` sheet, and then filling it down all the way to row 163803 would do what you need to do without needing any code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. I think it will do what you need.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Steward_Products()
    ' 236

    ' use descriptive names and use the declarations to explain them
    ' use Option Explicit and capitalization to avoid typos
    Dim WsSteward   As Worksheet                ' Demetri
    Dim WsDump      As Worksheet                ' Share_Dump
    Dim Fnd         As Range

    Set WsSteward = Worksheets("Demetri")
    Set WsDump = Worksheets("Share_Dump")

    With WsDump
        ' presuming that columns 28:38 are not longer than column 27
        Set Fnd = .Range(.Cells(4, 27), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 27).End(xlUp)) _
                  .Resize(, 12)
        
        Set Fnd = Fnd.Find(WsSteward.Cells(5, "J").Value, _
                           LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
        If Fnd Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Product """ & WsSteward.Cells(5, 10).Value & """ wasn't found.", _
                   vbInformation, "Invalid product description"
        Else
            .Cells(Fnd.Row, 57) = "Demetri"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```